# Ubuntu 22.04 - 4 monitors, GTX-960, HDMI monitor no signal but available in Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi

System Specs:

- Ryzen 9 3900x
- 64GB RAM
- GeForce GTX 960 (GM206)

  - Running nvidia-driver-515 (proprietary, tested)
- 4 Monitors connected to GTX 960, 3 on DP, 1 on HDMI

OS:

- Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
- Gnome 42.4
- Windowing X11

I've installed Ubuntu 22.04, but one of my monitors is showing as available in Ubuntu, but no signal on the monitor itself. Changing the monitor the HDMI cable is on moves the problem to that monitor, and all monitors work on Windows so I suspect a driver issue rather than an issue with the Monitor itself.

Outputs:

lsb_release -a:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

uname -a:

```
$ uname -a
Linux HostName 5.15.0-50-generic #56-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 20 13:23:26 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

xrandr: - Problem connection is HDMI-0

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 4920 x 2520, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+3000+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+1080+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 290mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
DP-2 connected 3440x1440+1080+1080 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 797mm x 333mm
   3440x1440    100.00*+  60.02  
   2560x1440     99.92    59.95  
   1920x1080    100.00    99.90    60.00    59.94    50.00    50.00  
   1680x1050     99.85    59.95  
   1440x900      99.93    59.89  
   1280x1024     99.96    75.02    60.02  
   1280x720      59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94    59.93  
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 connected 1080x1920+0+600 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       59.94  
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

sudo dmesg | grep drm:

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep drm
[    4.261167] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Module drm...
[    4.275398] systemd[1]: modprobe@drm.service: Deactivated successfully.
[    4.275550] systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module drm.
[    5.332037] [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000800] Loading driver
[    6.563315] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20160202 for 0000:08:00.0 on minor 0
[   22.839683] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000800] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   22.839743] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000800] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   22.839766] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000800] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   22.839789] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000800] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   22.870685] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000800] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   22.870742] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000800] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   22.870766] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000800] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   22.870789] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000800] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   22.902678] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000800] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   22.902761] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000800] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   22.902795] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000800] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   22.902826] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000800] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   60.081283] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000800] Failed to grab modeset ownership
```

dpkg -l | grep nvidia:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep nvidia
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-515:amd64                   515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                 amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-515                       515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                 all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
rc  libnvidia-compute-470:amd64                470.141.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-515:amd64                515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                 amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-515:i386                 515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                 i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-515:amd64                 515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                 amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-515:i386                  515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                 i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-egl-wayland1:amd64               1:1.1.9-1.1                                amd64        Wayland EGL External Platform library -- shared library
ii  libnvidia-encode-515:amd64                 515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                 amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-515:i386                  515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                 i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-extra-515:amd64                  515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                 amd64        Extra libraries for the NVIDIA driver
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-515:amd64                   515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                 amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-515:i386                    515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                 i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-515:amd64                     515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                 amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-515:i386                      515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                 i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
rc  nvidia-compute-utils-470                   470.141.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-515                   515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                 amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
rc  nvidia-dkms-470                            470.141.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-dkms-515                            515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                 amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-driver-515                          515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                 amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
rc  nvidia-kernel-common-470                   470.141.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-515                   515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                 amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-515                   515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                 amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                               0.8.17.1                                   all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                            510.47.03-0ubuntu1                         amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-515                           515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                 amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  screen-resolution-extra                    0.18.2                                     all          Extension for the nvidia-settings control panel
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515              515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                 amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version

```
$ cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  515.65.01  Wed Jul 20 14:00:58 UTC 2022
GCC version:  gcc version 11.2.0 (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1)
```

cat /sys/module/nvidia/version:

```
$ cat /sys/module/nvidia/version
515.65.01
```

dkms status:

```
$ dkms status
nvidia/515.65.01, 5.15.0-50-generic, x86_64: installed
```

I'm about to follow the answer from this question despite there being no mismatch as far as I'm aware: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70276412/how-to-fix-nvrm-api-mismatch-between-client-version-and-kernel-module-version

Edit: Above solution didn't work and I'm still down one monitor.

Would definitely like to get this sorted and open to ideas.